# Is it possible to programatically get the root node of an element?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I need to check if an element is contained in a given root node (model).

I'm currently querying the repository for all elements of type package with parent_ID=0, then getting the collection of elements in the root package and checking if the element is contained there.

```
function belongsToModel(element, model) {
var thequery = "SELECT * from t_object obj inner join t_package pkg on (obj.package_id = pkg.package_id) where obj.object_type = 'Package' and pkg.parent_ID=0"     
var thepackage;
var checkname;
var stereotypeElement;
var stereotypeElementsList = Repository.GetElementSet(thequery, 2);
var packageElement
var thePackageElement
var elementCollection

Session.Output("- Elements to process: " + stereotypeElementsList.Count);
for (var i = 0; i < stereotypeElementsList.Count; i++) {
    stereotypeElement = stereotypeElementsList.GetAt(i);
    var packageElement = Repository.GetPackageByID(stereotypeElement.PackageID);
    if (packageElement.Name == model){
        thePackageElement = stereotypeElement
        Session.Output("DEBUG packages: " + packageElement.Name + " element to check " + element.Name)
        elementCollection = thePackageElement.Elements;
        Session.Output("DEBUG Element Count: " + elementCollection.Count)
        checkname = elementCollection.GetByName(element.Name) 
        if (checkname != undefined){
            Session.Output("DEBUG element found: " + checkname.Name)
        }
    }
}
return checkname
}
```

However, this is not working and it really feels like a very rough workaround.

Is there any straightforward ways of checking this that I've missed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder why you make things that complicated. Just traverse the packageid of an element until you reach that with a zero-parent. There you are.

Something like (no specific language):

```
ptr = element.packageId
while ptr != 0 {
  root = ptr
  ptr = repository.getPackageById(ptr).parentId
}
```

`root` will finally hold the id of the root package.

Comment: That is indeed the best approach if you have to do it once. If you want to check that for a whole bunch of elements, or you want to query all elements in a branch, you'd want to go for the packageID's approach.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I was just guessing from the question title which states _an element_ which means one. And btw.: why didn't you use #branch#?

Comment: you can't use #Branch# from the API, only in the GUI, so I had to build my own #Branch# macro :)

Comment: @GeertBellekens Didn't they open that up to the API? At least they opened it up to the SQL scratch pad. Hmm. Inconsistent as ever...

Comment: actually this solution is perfect for me. thanks a lot!

Comment: Sometimes you dont see the forest before all the trees ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What you are now checking is if an element is stored directly under a root node (which it never will be) as EA forces you to create packages underneatch those first.

What you need to be checking is if an element is in a package that is in the **branch** started by root node.

The easiest way to figure that out is to first get a list of all packageID's of a branche, and then check if your element's PackageID is in that list.

Getting the packageID's using the API takes a lot of time, so it's faster if you do it using SQL queries.

### VBScript solution

From the [Util script](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-VBScript-Library/blob/master/Framework/Utils/Util.vbs)

```
'get the package id string of the given package tree
function getPackageTreeIDString(package)
    dim allPackageTreeIDs 
    set allPackageTreeIDs = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    dim parentPackageIDs
    set parentPackageIDs = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    if not package is nothing then
        parentPackageIDs.Add package.PackageID
    end if
    'get the actual package ids
    getPackageTreeIDsFast allPackageTreeIDs, parentPackageIDs
    'return
    getPackageTreeIDString = Join(allPackageTreeIDs.ToArray,",")
end function

function getPackageTreeIDsFast(allPackageTreeIDs, parentPackageIDs)
    if parentPackageIDs.Count = 0 then
        if allPackageTreeIDs.Count = 0 then
            'make sure there is at least a 0 in the allPackageTreeIDs
            allPackageTreeIDs.Add "0"
        end if
        'then exit
        exit function
    end if
    'add the parent package ids
    allPackageTreeIDs.AddRange(parentPackageIDs)
    'get the child package IDs
    dim sqlGetPackageIDs
    sqlGetPackageIDs = "select p.Package_ID from t_package p where p.Parent_ID in (" & Join(parentPackageIDs.ToArray, ",") & ")"
    dim queryResult
    set queryResult = getVerticalArrayListFromQuery(sqlGetPackageIDs)
    if queryResult.Count > 0 then
        dim childPackageIDs
        set childPackageIDs = queryResult(0)
        'call recursive function with child package id's
        getPackageTreeIDsFast allPackageTreeIDs, childPackageIDs
    end if
end function

function getVerticalArrayListFromQuery(sqlQuery)
    dim xmlResult
    xmlResult = Repository.SQLQuery(sqlQuery)
    set getVerticalArrayListFromQuery = convertQueryResultToVerticalArrayList(xmlResult)
end function

Function convertQueryResultToVerticalArrayList(xmlQueryResult)
    Dim result
    set result = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim xDoc 
    Set xDoc = CreateObject( "MSXML2.DOMDocument" )
    'load the resultset in the xml document
    If xDoc.LoadXML(xmlQueryResult) Then        
        'select the rows
        Dim rowList
        Set rowList = xDoc.SelectNodes("//Row")
        Dim rowNode 
        Dim fieldNode
        dim firstRow
        firstRow = true
        'loop rows and find fields
        For Each rowNode In rowList
            if firstRow then
                For Each fieldNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
                    'add an arraylist for each column
                    result.Add CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
                next
            end if
            'loop the field nodes
            dim i
            i = 0
            For Each fieldNode In rowNode.ChildNodes
                'add the contents to the correct column arraylist
                result(i).Add fieldNode.Text
                i = i + 1
            Next
        Next
    end if
    set convertQueryResultToVerticalArrayList = result
end function
```

### C# solution

From the [Package class](https://github.com/GeertBellekens/Enterprise-Architect-Add-in-Framework/blob/master/EAAddinFramework/EAWrappers/Package.cs)

```
    private List<string> getPackageTreeIDs(List<string> parentIDs = null)
    {
        List<string> allPackageIDs = new List<string>();
        List<string> subPackageIDs = new List<string>();
        if (parentIDs == null)
        {
            parentIDs = new List<string>() { this.packageID.ToString() };
        }
        //add the current parentID's to the list of all ID's
        allPackageIDs.AddRange(parentIDs);
        //get the id's from the subpackages
        string parentIDString = string.Join(",", parentIDs);
        string getSubpackageSQL = "select p.Package_ID from t_package p where p.Parent_ID in (" + parentIDString + ")";
        var queryResult = this.EAModel.SQLQuery(getSubpackageSQL);
        foreach (XmlNode packageIdNode in queryResult.SelectNodes(this.EAModel.formatXPath("//Package_ID")))
        {
            subPackageIDs.Add(packageIdNode.InnerText);
        }
        //if subpackages found then go a level deeper
        if (subPackageIDs.Any())
        {
            allPackageIDs.AddRange(this.getPackageTreeIDs(subPackageIDs));
        }
        return allPackageIDs;
    }
```